# Flask tutorial: Stylesheet does not work

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have an exact copy of this [flaskr folder](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr). I ran the application. Everything works as expected but one thing. My blog application is not styled even though I have a 'style.css' file in the folder names static.

In the .html files of the template folder it seems the author forgot to put quotes. So I added quotes such that those files now look like this ([layout.html](http://pastebin.com/2dzedpnM), [logout.html](http://pastebin.com/EKyUh5q0) and [show_entries.html](http://pastebin.com/z8ZAZpFr) . But it didn't change anything, still see an unstyled blog. Does anyone know why the style is not applied?

---

Edit: 
I restarted the app. And all of a sudden I get an `OperationalError: no such table exists: entries`(see [here](http://pastebin.com/P6Jd6Hmu)). Yesterday I filled in 1 entry in the blog, but it worked fine and correctly displayed the entry except for the style. Now all of a sudden the first time I run the application today I get this completely new error. I recopied all files again just like in the author's folder to make sure its the exact same flaskr folder of the author. I get the same error.

Can somebody copy the [author's flaskr folder](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr) and run `python flaskr.py` in the flaskr directory to see if it works for them? So at least I know then that the source is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the edit:
I forgot to run:
`>>> from flaskr import init_db; init_db()` (see readme file).

I don't know why the style did not apply last time, but now it does.

Answer (score 0):

The style sheets might not be loading

Use a tool like firebug to make sure the style sheets are actually being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and the below solution worked for me.
If you go to the `__init__.py` file and change

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
```

to

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")
```

It should work. My guess is that the default directory doesn't get set correctly without the additional arguments. This sets the static url path to folder with `__init__.py` in it and the static folder to a folder in the same directory named "static". If you have the folder somewhere else or named differently you would need to change those two arguments.